# ImageView onMeasure in a horizontal RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have a horizontal RecyclerView in my layout that is populated with a CustomImageView which ensures a rounded drawable inside it. When I add these custom views, their width is zero. This RecyclerView is defined as this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/chart_months_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/saltpan"
    />
```

Pretty simple. Referring to my CustomImageView, this is the code and their layout:

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {
    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Drawable d = getDrawable();
        if (d != null) {
            int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int h = w * d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            double f1 = ((double)w)*0.78;
            double f2 = ((double)h)*0.78;
            setMeasuredDimension((int)f1, (int)f2);
            Log.e("MEASURE", f1+" "+f2);
        }
        else super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_cell"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_cell_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="2.5dp"
    android:paddingRight="2.5dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <org.madebyalex.myperiod.CustomImageView
            android:id="@+id/chart_cell_background"
            android:src="@drawable/ball"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chart_month_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="AAAA"
                android:textColor="@color/saltpan"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This code works properly. I use it in other parts and layout is fully presented. This layout is used in a class with this ctor:

```
public ChartMonthItem( Context context, RecyclerViewItemClickListener itemClickListener ){
    super( context );

    this.context           = context;
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    selected               = false;

    View view = LayoutInflater.from( context ).inflate( R.layout.chart_select_option_text_image, this );
    CustomImageView backgroundMonth  = ( CustomImageView )findViewById( R.id.chart_cell_background );
    backgroundMonth.setMinimumWidth( 100 );
    drawable                         = backgroundMonth.getDrawable();
    chartMonthNumber                 = ( TextView )findViewById( R.id.chart_month_number );
}
```

I forced my ImageView to a minimum width of 100 just for test. Calling invalidate() doesn't work too. after Even with this approach it continues to have a width of zero.
I hoped with this approach I was ensuring a minimum width and the created ImageViews would have proper width based on their parent.

What I doing wrong?